# pass arguments into anchor after sql query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, anchor, database-table

how can I to perform this operation?

```
    this->datatables->select('first_name','roll_num')
    -> from('students')
    -> add_column('cancel',anchor("cancel/<first_name>/<roll_num>", 'Delete', array('onClick' =>"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')")));
```

I need to pass `first_name` and `roll_num` for this one. How to pass these arguments into anchor.

Thanks for the help!

actually i am able to do it using    ->add_column('cancel','Delete,','first_num',roll_num');

but since i want a yes/no conformation I want the above syntax .... Is there any other way to add yes/no conformation to it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible this way. You will have first to retrieve the result (as an associative array) and then call Codeigniter's `anchor` function on the result. Your RDBMS is totally ignorant of the anchor function.

Something that might look like this :

```
$query = $this->datatables->select('first_name','roll_num')
->from('students')
->get();

$results = $query->result();

anchor("cancel/{$results[0]->first_name}/{$results[0]->roll_num}", 'Delete', array('onClick' =>"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"));
```

I did not tried the above code, so it might have some synthax fixing, but I thinkthe general solution is there.